# How to show $|(1-z)e^z| \geq e^{-|z|^2}$ for all $|z| \leq 1/2$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove the above inequality, but keep running into difficulties. It seems breaking up the RHS into $e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$ doesn't help much, and similarly writing LHS $\geq |e^{z}| - |z||e^{z}|$ isn't useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can take the logarithm of $(1-z)e^z$, using the principal branch, that gives

$$\log \left((1-z)e^z\right) = z + \log (1-z) = z - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k} = - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}.$$

Now, to get the logarithm of the absolute modulus of $(1-z)e^z$, we take the real part. We exaggerate by using the absolute modulus and find

$$\begin{align}
\log \left\lvert (1-z)e^z\right\rvert &=
\operatorname{Re} \log \left((1-z)e^z\right)\\
&= - \operatorname{Re}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}\\
&\geqslant - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\lvert z\rvert^k}{k}\\
&\geqslant - \frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}{2} \sum_{\nu=0}^\infty \lvert z\rvert^\nu\\
&= - \frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}{2} \frac{1}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\\
&\geqslant - \lvert z\rvert^2,
\end{align}$$

since $\dfrac{1}{1-\lvert z\rvert} \leqslant 2$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \frac12$.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.  +1.  I thought I could find a simpler proof, but even the inequality $|1-z|\ge 1 - |z|$ is already too unforgiving.  Well done!